# Adding JavaScript calculation function to HTML form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

I am trying to link a basic calculation in an external JavaScript 
The form is pretty simple and the function just checks to make sure the step number is even.  I have reviewed the code many times, but when I enter the numbers and hit submit nothing happens. Any suggestions? Its seems like I just don't have the function and input elements linked correctly. 
here is the code:

```js
function evenNumbers() {
var evenNumberBtn = document.querySelector("button");
evenNumberBtn.addEventListener("click", evenNumbers);
    var startNumber = parseInt(document.getElementById("startNumber").value);
    var endNumber = parseInt(document.getElementById("endNumber").value);
    var stepNumber = parseInt(document.getElementById("stepNumber").value);
        while (startNumber + stepNumber <= endNumber) {  
            if (startNumber <= endNumber){
                if (startNumber % 2 === 0 && stepNumber % 2 === 0) {
                    startNumber += stepNumber;
                    alert(startNumber);
                } else if (startNumber % 2 !== 0 && stepNumber % 2 === 0) {
                     startNumber += 1 + (stepNumber);
                     alert(startNumber);
                } else {
                     alert("Please enter a positive number for the step value.");
                } 

             } else {
                  alert("Please enter an ending number greater than the start number.");
             }
        }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML5, CSS3 and JavaScript demo</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
  <label>Start: </label>
  <input type="number" id="startNumber"/><br/>
  <label>End: </label>
  <input type="number" id="endNumber"/><br/>
  <label>Step by:</label>
    <input type="number" id="stepNumber"/><br/>
  <button onclick="evenNumbers();">Submit</button>
    <p></p>
  </form>

<!-- End your code here -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
In .js file

```
var evenNumberBtn = document.querySelector("button");
evenNumberBtn.addEventListener("click", evenNumbers);
```

Comment: I added that, but still does nothing when submit is pressed

Answer (score 0):

I have removed your actual code for now, because it has some issues whereby you can end up in an infinite loop (I definitely did and it crashed Chrome ).

Your issue was in your HTML

Before

```
<button onclick("evenNumbers();")>Submit</button>
```

After

```
<button onclick="evenNumbers();">Submit</button>
```

```js
        function evenNumbers() {
        var startNumber = parseInt(document.getElementById("startNumber").value);
        var endNumber = parseInt(document.getElementById("endNumber").value);
        var stepNumber = parseInt(document.getElementById("stepNumber").value);
        alert(startNumber + ',' + endNumber + ',' + stepNumber);
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>HTML5, CSS3 and JavaScript demo</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <form>
      <label>Start: </label>
      <input type="text" id="startNumber"/><br/>
      <label>End: </label>
      <input type="text" id="endNumber"/><br/>
      <label>Step by:</label>
        <input type="text" id="stepNumber"/><br/>
      <button onclick="evenNumbers();">Submit</button>
        <p></p>
      </form>

    <!-- End your code here -->
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function evenNumbers() {
//var evenNumberBtn = document.querySelector("button");
//evenNumberBtn.addEventListener("click", evenNumbers);
    var startNumber = parseInt(document.getElementById("startNumber").value);
    var endNumber = parseInt(document.getElementById("endNumber").value);
    var stepNumber = parseInt(document.getElementById("stepNumber").value);
        while (startNumber + stepNumber <= endNumber) {  
            if (startNumber <= endNumber){
                if (startNumber % 2 === 0 && stepNumber % 2 === 0) {
                    startNumber += stepNumber;
                    alert(startNumber);
                } else if (startNumber % 2 !== 0 && stepNumber % 2 === 0) {
                     startNumber += 1 + (stepNumber);
                     alert(startNumber);
                } else {
                     alert("Please enter a positive number for the step value.");
                } 

             } else {
                  alert("Please enter an ending number greater than the start number.");
             }
        }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML5, CSS3 and JavaScript demo</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
  <label>Start: </label>
  <input type="text" id="startNumber"/><br/>
  <label>End: </label>
  <input type="text" id="endNumber"/><br/>
  <label>Step by:</label>
    <input type="text" id="stepNumber"/><br/>
  <button onclick="evenNumbers()">Submit</button>
    <p></p>
  </form>

<!-- End your code here -->
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The first two lines inside evenNumber function need to be outside the function, Otherwise your code never reaches inside that block.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

  var evenNumberBtn = document.querySelector("button");
  evenNumberBtn.addEventListener("click", evenNumbers);
  function evenNumbers() {
    /*

       your code here

    */
  }    

});
```

Also the logic inside the evenNumbers seems wrong. You might need to change that too.